# Safari Offline Online Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a one page site with included jquery (i copied the whole jQuery v3.2.1 into the head in  a script-tag)
It works fine in all browsers on a PC that I have offline and online (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera).
Only with Safari on the Imac and Macbook it works only online not offline.

I dont want to post the whole code here, but has anyone an idea why that could be?
Is that a settings thing in the browser?
If i upload the single file to our server, Safari displays it nicely. If I open it on the desktop on Macs, the JS/JQuery is not executed ...

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  //localStorage.clear();
  wert = 0;
  if (localStorage.getItem("wert") !== null) {
    wert = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("wert")) + 1;
  }

  fenster_anzahl = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("wert", wert));
  for (var i = 1; i <= fenster_anzahl; i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('site_' + i) !== null) {
      $(".arrowcontainer").hide(0);
      saved_url = localStorage.getItem('site_' + i);
      //alert(i);
      $("#content").prepend('<div class="wrap wrapadded" style="overflow:hidden;"><iframe  class="added-iframe" style="transform: scale(0.75);transform-origin: -15% 0;  width:150%; height:1800px;" src="' + saved_url + '" name=""></iframe><button class="deletebutton" id="site_' + i + '">x</button></div>');
    }
  }



  $("#content").on("click", ".deletebutton", function() {

    $(this).parent().hide();
    localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr('id'));
  });

  $(".addbutton").mouseup(function() {
    $("#content").prepend('<div class="wrap wrapadded" style="overflow:hidden;"><div style="margin-top:80px;">Bitte URL des Airtrackers eingeben</div><br><input type="text" class="url_eingeben" style="height:40px; width:200px; margin-top:50px; border:0px; font-size:15pt; padding:20px; background:#013780; color:#FFF" value="http://"><br><button class="bestaetigen" style="padding: 20px; margin-top:50px;">Bestätigen</button><button class="deletebutton" id="site_' + wert + '">x</button></div>');
    $(".arrowcontainer").fadeOut(200);

  });





  function addURL(obj, url) {

    wert = parseInt(wert) + 1;
    obj.parent().closest('div').html('<iframe  class="added-iframe" style="transform: scale(0.75);transform-origin: 0 0;  width:150%; height:1800px;" src="' + url + '" name=""></iframe><button class="deletebutton" id="site_' + wert + '">x</button>');
    localStorage.setItem("site_" + wert, url);
    localStorage.setItem("wert", wert);

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#site_" + wert).contents();

      iFrameDOM.find("body").css("background", "#f00");
    });

  }




  $("#content").on("click", ".bestaetigen", function(e) {
    var url = $(this).prevAll('input').val();
    addURL($(this), url);
  });
  $("#content").on("keyup", ".url_eingeben", function(e) {

    if (e.which == 13) {
      var url = $(this).val();
      addURL($(this), url);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it is too long ... and I dont see the reason is in the code since it works in all browsers on and offline ...

Comment: It's possible that you are using either absolute paths or incorrectly using relative paths for the JavaScript files.

Comment: try check in ur browser console then, you might able to find some info or error

Comment: @pathurs: I have no paths in the file. The library is pasted into the head tag like this : <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script> 
   /*! jQuery v3.2.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
!function(a,b){"use  ......</script>

Comment: [Open the console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), tell what error messages you see.

Comment: I cannot check in the console. I do not have a Mac. I just saw and was told that it does not work. I do not have access to it atm.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading your HTML page by double-clicking the `.html` file in Finder, that could be your problem. This opens the page with a `file:` URL which has some restrictions on it.

In particular, your code uses `localStorage`, and in at least some browsers, [`file:` URLs cannot use `localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Instead, run a local web server and then load the page with an `http:` URL. One easy way to do this is with a simple Python command.

It's been a while since I checked, but I believe OSX/macOS comes with Python preinstalled. Open a Terminal window and `cd` to the directory that has your `.html` page in it.

Then type `python --version` to see what version of Python you have.

If the version is 2.something, use this command to start a web server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

If it is 3.something, use:

```
python -m http.server
```

Whichever one you use, it will start a web server in your directory and will display the port it is listening on. It should default to port 8000.

Now open Safari and enter the `localhost` URL for your file. If the server is running on port 8000 and the file is called `mypage.html`, use:

```
http://localhost:8000/mypage.html
```

By doing it this way you will avoid any restrictions that are imposed on `file:` URLs.

Also, instead of pasting the entire jQuery source code into your HTML file, I recommend keeping jQuery in a separate `.js` file. Save it as `jquery.js` in the same directory as your .html file, and then load it in your HTML with `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`.

Also it is best to use the uncompressed development version of jQuery if you're currently using the compressed (minified) version. This way you will be able to read the jQuery code more easily to help you understand what it is doing or to interpret any stack traces. [Download it here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js) and save it as `jquery.js` in the same directory as your `.html` file.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your input. As I said I do not have access to a Mac atm to check if your suggestion works. But I will likely accept your answer after I get a test macbook tomorrow.

I am aware of the use of a separate file, but for simplicity reasons we wanted to keep all in one file that a user can download. For the same reason I also base64 encoded the single image that is inside, so that I do not need to reference it.